# How to aggregate data in Spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch 5.

My problem is that I am not sure of the best way of dealing with aggregation of data in Spring Batch, and have yet to succeed in creating an application that successfully aggregates data and writes it to a table.

I have a DB table with one type of records that I need to read, then process (aggregate and convert to another type of record), then write to another DB table. I need to do this for anywhere between 100 to a million+ records.

For simplicity sake: My 2 tables has the following:

- One with location_id, datetime and hourly values.
- One with location_id, datetime and daily values, aggregated from hourly values.

I'm positive there is some aspect I'm missing in Spring Batch or maybe I'm too used to be able to read a List of Objects I can work with, with a plain old JDBC connector.

Am I supposed to fetch a List of hourly values, then process the entire dataset, where I have access to all the hourly values I need to aggregate and then write that list to the DB table? Or am I supposed to process each individual record and somehow aggregate that?

This is my first post; Let me know if I need to explain anything in further detail.

Since I couldn't find a way to aggregate data when only providing the JdbcCursorItemReader as this: `JdbcCursorItemReader<HourlyValue>`
due to only having access to each single record of HourlyValue when processing the item, I couldn't figure out how to aggregate. I therefore went for another method of reading data where I had the ItemReader return a List of HourlyValue.

I'll provide a code snippet of my JdbcItemCursorReader which fetches 1 days worth of hourly values with some hardcoded values for the example.

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<List<HourlyValue>> hourlyValueItemReader(DataSource dataSource) {

        String sql = "SELECT location_id, datetime, hourly_value " +
                "FROM hourly_values " +
                "WHERE datetime >= '2023-10-24 22:00' AND datetime < '2023-10-25 22:00' " +
                "ORDER BY location_id, datetime";

        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<List<HourlyValue>>()
                .name("fetchOneDayOfHourlyValues")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql(sql)
                .verifyCursorPosition(false)
                .rowMapper(new HourlyValuesRowMapper()) 
                .build();
    }
```

The HourlyValuesRowMapper implements the RowMapper and adds all the HourlyValue objects to a List and returns the List.
My processor aggregates the hourly values into daily values and returns a List of DailyValues.
At this point I have all the data I need, my ItemWriter just aren't able to write it to the DB, since it tries to write an ArrayList to the DB instead of each DailyValue.

My ItemWriter looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<List<DailyValue>> dailyValueItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<List<DailyValue>>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql("INSERT INTO daily_values " +
                        "(id, location_id, date, daily_value) " +
                        "VALUES(:id, :locationId, :date, :dailyValue)")
                .beanMapped()
                .build();
    }
```

As mentioned earlier, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can think on custom item reader and custom item writer in this case [custom](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/readers-and-writers/custom.html)

Comment: How would you do that without spring batch? What about doing the aggregation in SQL? That would be more efficient than doing it on the application side.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Aggregation in the SQL is definitely an option for this case. My initial thoughts on aggregating the data in the processor was due to the fact that I have some bitwise operations that I would like to be able to either log or debug.